# How can I get the logging from phpseclib and SFTP?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I am using below code to transfer files to an SFTP server

```
use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;

$sftp = new SFTP('localhost');

$sftp->login('user', 'password');
error_log($sftp->pwd());

foreach ($fileList as $key => $value) {
    $output = $sftp->put("//data//myfile.txt, //sourceFile.txt, SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);
    error_log($output);
}

error_log($sftp->getLastError());
// error_log($sftp->getSFTPLastError());
error_log('------------------------------------');
error_log("<pre>" . print_r($sftp->getErrors(), true) . "</pre>");
// error_log("<pre>" . print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors(), true) . "</pre>");
error_log("<pre>" . print_r($sftp->getLog(), true) . "</pre>");
error_log("<pre>" . print_r($sftp->getSFTPLog(), true) . "</pre>");
```

which works fine. The only issue I have is that it is not throwing any error messages if it fails (only $output becomes null).
What do I need to change to get proper logging messages or at least responses from the SFTP server in case of any issues?

Comment: The `put()` method should return a boolean, never null, so I'm guessing `false` is being returned. Looking at the [source of the put method](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/fa53d1180734e605ab25278f71404cdbf60d4f08/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L1816), there are several places where it returns `false` without logging anything, it might be worth putting some breakpoints or similar in those places to determine where the return is happening

Comment: @ChrisHaas I was looking for a way to get some logging details without hacking the original source.

Comment: I totally understand that. What I'm saying is that some things aren't logged, and you might need to temporarily hack it, just to see if maybe you are making an error, or if there's a bug in their code

Comment: `error_log("<pre>" . print_r($sftp->getSFTPLog(), true) . "</pre>");` - you'd need to do `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', 2)` at the top of the file for that to work. But, ultimately, I'd say that getting the SFTP logs is probably going to be the most helpful thing for you to do. Get them, post them on pastebin.com and then edit your post to include a link to it. And then reply here with an `@neubert` comment.

Comment: @neubert thanks for your input, that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copying @neubert comment here to show the correct answer to my question:

> you'd need to do define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', 2) at the top of the file for that to work.